# Android set application icon in manifest file from external resources

Tags: android

I am trying to change App icon from external file so Is there any way to set application icon in manifest from build.gradle or local.properties file ?

Comment: why you need build.gradle file to change app icon ? what about mipmaps or drawables ?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. You can use different drawables for different build types

Comment: No. You don't have any runtime permission to do this.

Comment: need  to change app icon from local.properties file , so is there any way ?

Comment: @aj0822ArpitJoshi Does this not answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can have different resources in different `sourceSets`.

For example:
If you have different icon images in sourceSet `main`, `debug` and `release`, the project will use the respective icons from the folders.

`src/main/res/drawable/icon.png`

`src/debug/res/drawable/icon.png`

`src/release/res/drawable/icon.png`

and so on.

And use them in the `AndroidManifest.xml` as:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

Read about creating source sets here: [Create Source Sets](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourcesets)

Another way of doing this is using [Manifest Placeholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html) to inject variables in the `AndroidManifest`.